# Object Reference error in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I had applied the following code :

```
var country = from cnty in this.GetAll<CompanyDefinition>().ToList()
   where cnty.IsImported = true
   select new { 
      CompanyDefinitionID = cnty.CompanyDefinitionID
      , CompanyDefinitionName = cnty.Company.CompanyName + "(" + cnty.Country.CountryCode + "," + cnty.NaicsCode.NaicsCode1 + ")"
};
```

And I am getting Object Reference error. Its pointing to "select new". Whats the correct way?

Comment: The `ToList()` is redundant when you query the list immediately after anyway. Create the list at the end from the result of the query.

Comment: This is the correct way, but `Company` or `Country` or `NaicsCode` in `null` on one of your `CompanyDefinition`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `Company`, `Country` or `NaicsCode` is `null`, you would need to check this before attempting to access their properties. For example, you could re-write your query as:

```
var country = from cnty in this.GetAll<CompanyDefinition>()
              where cnty.IsImported && cnty.Company != null && cnty.Country != null && cnty.NaicsCode != null
              select new {
                  ...
              }
```

Comment: +1, bang on. Also add `Country` to the list of probable `null` object references.

Comment: @code4life yeah I scanned over `Company`, first glance I thought it was `Country`! Updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are employing lazy loading, then using `ToList()` method is not proper. After calling `ToList()`, `IQueryable<>` object is materialized to `IEnumerable<>`; thus database is not queried for `Company` or `Country` references. Try removing  `ToList()` function.

Comment: Or moving it to after the query.

Comment: Although this is sound advice, this isn't what the problem is.